# python: pip fails to install matplotlib v.3.1.1

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

```
% pip -r requirements.txt
```

where requirements.txt has the following line:

matplotlib==3.1.1

Command fails:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==3.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (from versions: 0.86, 0.86.1, 0.86.2, 0.91.0, 0.91.1, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1rc1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0b2, 2.0.0b3, 2.0.0b4, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 3.0.0rc2, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib==3.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
```

I tried both `pip install -r requirements.txt` and `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` with no difference.

Although `pip search matplotlib` does show that "matplotlib (3.1.3)" is available. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: OS? Python version? `pip` version? 32- or 64-bit Python?